# Org-mode inline .eps images display error. (.eps created by AI ok, .eps created by matplotlib no)

Tags: org-mode, inline-image

As I basically use `Org` to take note and export LaTeX files, I find displaying eps files as inline image to be important for me.I have my emacs compiled with ImageMagick support, and added the following codes in the `.emacs` file to enable inline preview support of `.eps` files link in `Org-mode`

```
(add-to-list 'image-type-file-name-regexps '("\\.eps\\'" . imagemagick)  )
(add-to-list 'image-file-name-extensions "eps")
(setq org-image-actual-width '(400))
```

I have tested an .eps file created by `matplotlib` using `Agg` backend, which the rendered inline image is blank. 
However when converting the eps file using Adobe Illustrator to Illustrator EPS (I have tried several versions from AI 3 to AI CC) and the converted eps file can be successfully shown as inline image.

[image]

Since the `org-display-inline-images` function only takes the image created by `ImageMagick` to make the overlay,
this problem seems to be due to be caused by `ImageMagick` failing to render the `matplotlib` version eps file. However if using the ImageMagick from system command line like `convert -density 300 test.eps test.png` will correctly create the png file which can be opened by system preview.

The question is, what exactly is the difference between the eps created by matplotlib and AI?

> The test is done in OS X El Capitan with emacs 25.1.1, org-mode 8.2.0, matplotlib 2.0.0b4 and Adobe Illustrator CC 2015.  [The sample files (.org + .eps files created by matplotlib and AI)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ju9yv1fpv53tvsf/tese_org_eps.zip?dl=0)